# repeat only once character regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to match repeat character(/) only once in the middle of the string. At the start it must be http://www.website/shop. Now I am using this code and it matches all html. How can I restrict it.

'^[http://www.website/shop/].*.html$'

With this regex, no result
   ^[http://]\W*(/){2}\W

Valid

```
   http://www.website/shop/men.html
   http://www.website/shop/women.html
```

Invalid

```
   http://www.website/shop/men/footwear.html
   http://www.website/shop/men/causal.html
   http://www.website/shop/women/footwear.html
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking? I can't see how you expect valid and invalid to be any different...

Comment: `\W` is opposite of `\w`, i.e. it's any character except letters and numbers...

Answer (score 1):

This regex should work

```
"http://www.website/shop/\w*.html"
```

... it won't match if there's another slash after the slashes in `.../shop/`

Comment: it is working but how about the link like "http://www.website/shop/men+hair.html". If I use your answer, I cannot get this kind of link.

Comment: this doesn't generate any html. The restrictions must start with "http://www.website/shop/" and regex must not match the string if it has another slash. And the string can also have + in the middle of the html. Any ideas?

Comment: give me an example of when it fails so i can make sure i understand what you're saying

Comment: http://www.website/shop/men+hair.html
http://www.website/shop/women+hair.html
http://www.website/shop/women+accessories.html
http://www.website/shop/baby.html

Comment: These are not matched with http://www.website/shop/\w*\+*\w*.html. The program is just terminated.

Comment: I don't remember this anymore, but there might be a typo in my comment, try: "website/shop/\w*\+*\w*.html" instead... note the / after shop.